# Do ASP.Net Validation Controls work *before* the first postback?

Tags: asp.net, validation

We are investigating using ASP.Net validations for client side validating.  Is it possible to get the client side validators to work before an initial postback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly. The validation controls will work before the page is posted back. What do you mean by "before an initial postback"?

Comment: In experimenting with the controls I have noticed that Client Side validations don't seem to work until after the submit button is pressed.  Then after the first postback, then validations will take place onBlur. I have only experimented with the RequiredFieldValidator so far..

Comment: When implemented correctly, client-side validation occurs after the submit button is pressed, and before the page is posted back. And, if the validation does not pass, no postback occurs.